# Windows 7:How to remove file types from all file explorer

Tags: windows-7

I would like to remove the file type column from all of the sub folders of a specific directory. **If I do it the way depicted in the picture, it will not affect the subfolders**. Please give me a hint. Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must click on "Apply to all folders" in Explorer options:

[image]

Now Windows uses the view for all folders (which match the current folder type like video, music, pictures, documents, general)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Right click on the column bar and click on `More`.
2. Check (`add`) and uncheck (`remove`) columns from the available listed details that you want to add or remove, then click on `OK` when finished.

[image]

Comment: Does not apply those setting to subfolders, it affect only the current folder